# How to install ATI Radeon Graphic drivers on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon

I have recently updates my 5 yrs old HP dv5 AMD laptop to Ubuntu 14.04, all good so far just that I am not able to grasp the right process to install drivers for the ATI Radeon card provided in this laptop.

Though I am happy with the current graphics on the monitor just that I am not able to change the resolution setting, default I am getting below options:

"1280 x 800" and below, nothing over it.

I am new to Ubuntu/Linux so how should I install the correct drivers to allow me to get the correct resolution?

Answer (score 4):

You can follow the official [Ubuntu how-to guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD).

In short - open your terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

Then generate a fresh xorg.conf, before you reboot:

```
sudo amdconfig --initial
```

Reboot. It is a good idea to read the whole article that I have linked to you. There you can find examples how you can backup you current settings and restore them if something fails.

Comment: Note: fglrx is not supported on 14.04.5...
See here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver at the paragraph mentioning HWE stack Xenial.

Answer (score 0):

Open System Settings. Click on Software & Updates. Click on the additional drivers tab. You should then be able to select another graphics card driver and click Apply Changes.